# Visual Studio open "record CPU Profile" to measure application performance by analyzing CPU usage but get empty result

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2019

I follow microsoft doc [Measure application performance by analyzing CPU usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/beginners-guide-to-performance-profiling?view=vs-2019)

open `"record CPU Profile"`
[image]

I tried it but there's no expected result like doc

[image]

My Visual Studio information

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.9.4
```

My Test Code

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test1();
        }

        public static void Test1()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000*1; i++)
                i.ToString();
            Test2();
        }

        public static void Test2()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000 * 10; i++)
                i.ToString();
            Test3();
        }

        public static void Test3()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000 * 100; i++)
                i.ToString();
            Test4();
        }

        public static void Test4()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000 * 10000; i++)
                i.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Why I do it, because I want to know each method wasting time.

---

updated:

Gif:
[image: 20210419]

Comment: What items are selected in your `Filter` dropdown?

Comment: @TimothyG. [image](https://i.imgur.com/skc3A67.png), I selected all threads

Comment: All of your threads for some reason show 0%, and when I tested this in my Visual Studio, I would only get the message you are receiving when I selected a thread with 0% usage. So that is probably your issue.  No idea why every single one is 0% for you... Have you breakpointed on a piece of code in your project and examined what happens?

Comment: @Timothy G , thanks, I upload [gif](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/12729184/119788619-dfc5f900-bf04-11eb-9bff-8162997879f1.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by `Debug \ Performance Profiler`

[image]

And select `Instrumentation`

[image]

Then click `Start` system can return methods exection time

[image]

---

and I notice it can't show `project reference` methods execution time summary

[image]
[image]

---

updated:

It can show reference execution time, by select multiple project

[image]
[image]

---

Update :

I notice project have to same TargetFramework version, or it'll throw below exception

[image]

[image]